# Dynamic components in email templates

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, email-template

I need to create a dynamic system that allows me to pick up a concrete component based on a field, this needs to occur in an email template.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate relatedToType="Opportunity">
    if(relatedTo.Country== 'Spain'){
        <c:spanishOppComponent />
    }else{
        <c:oppComponent />
    }
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

How can I achieve the below pseudo code in an email template?

Answer (score 3):

You can embed your components inside a `apex:outputPanel`. Then, you can control the `rendered` property of theses panels. Like this:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(relatedTo.Country = 'Spain', true, false)}">
    <c:spanishOppComponent />
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(relatedTo.Country <> 'Spain', true, false)}">
    <c:oppComponent />
</apex:outputPanel>
```